# Complied simple batch file to exe not working

Tags: batch-file, compilation, exe, relative-path

I created a batch file that opens a relative link. It works great, but I'd prefer to change it to an executable file with an icon. Here's the code for Meal Master.bat:

```
"code\index.html"
```

Here's my directory:

```
Meal Master
    Meal Master.bat
    code
        index.html
        style.css
        (other files for the offline website)
```

I used this link as a tutorial: http://hintdesk.com/how-to-create-relative-shortcut-to-exe-file-with-icon/.

The batch file opens the offline website with the default browser perfectly. However, once I followed the tutorial and made the exe, a small window pops up and says "Error! An unknown error occurred. The program will be terminated."

How can I make an exe or relative shortcut that works (or any kind of file with an icon)?

Comment: Update: For some reason, it works when I select "visible application" and don't use an icon in the compiler.

Comment: Bat-to-Exe converters are garbage, never use them.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Is there any other way to do this? I just want a file that you can double click that opens my relative link, with an icon.

Comment: Make a copy of the Command-prompt icon, right click on it, click on "Properties" and set the ones that allows to run your Batch file: change "Start dir" to the one where the Batch file is; then change "Target" and add `/C BatchFile.bat` after `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe`. This way, when you double-click on this icon, your Batch file will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! This was a little tricky because I had to randomly change options in the bat-to-exe converter. Don't use an icon, and make it visible. After that, use something like Resource Hacker (http://download.cnet.com/Resource-Hacker/3000-2352_4-10178587.html). Action > Add a new resource. Select your icon, and change the resource name to icon. That's it! It works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file text file `RunFile.vb` on the desktop.

Paste this in to it.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module MyApplication  


Sub Main()
    Dim X as Object
    X = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    X.Run("c:\windows\notepad.exe")
End Sub
End Module
```

To make a program type this

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\RunFile.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop\RunFile.vb" /verbose
```

`X.Run` can be anything you can type into the Start Run dialog (WinKey + R)

**Help Windows Find Programs and Documents**

Programs and documents can be added to the registry so typing their name without their path in the Start - Run dialog box or shortcut enables Windows to find them.

This is a generic reg file. Copy the lines below to a new Text Document and save it as anyname.reg. Edit it with your programs or documents.

In paths use \ to separate folder names in key paths as regedit uses a single \ to separate it's key names. All reg files start with REGEDIT4. A semicolon turns a line into a comment. The @ symbol means to assign the value to the key rather than a named value.

The file doesn't have to exist. This can be used to set Word.exe to open Winword.exe. **Or by registering a non existent website.exe to point at website.html allows you to open website.html just by typing website.**

This sample add IE.Txt (from IE5) to the registry so typing IE.Txt will open it. I think the file is called IE4.txt in IE4.
REGEDIT4
;The bolded name below is the name of the document or program, .

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IE.txt]

;The @ means the path to the file is assigned to the default value for the key.
;The whole path in enclosed in a quotation mark ".

@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IE.txt\""

;Optional Parameters. The semicolon means don't process the line. Remove it if you want to put it in the registry

;Informs the shell that the program accepts URLs.

;"useURL"="1"

;Sets the path that a program will use as its' default directory. This is commented out.

;"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office\\"
```

Comment: This works great for absolute locations, and it can have an icon with Resource Hacker. However, I was looking for relative locations (unless I'm missing something with the X.Run value). Thanks anyway.

Comment: It does relative paths as well. But relative paths are configuration dependent. It depends on console/GUI, on how it was started, and folder structure, so sample code that works on my computer may not work on yours.

Comment: Also even my fully qualified path won't work on computers that have been upgraded from Win NT4 as Windows directory was called WinNT (and it keeps the NT4 name during upgrades). I should have specified `%windir%\system32\notepad.exe` which will work all versions of windows.